# Generalization to a non-algebraically closed field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider $V$ to be some affine space and a set $X\subset V\times\mathbb{P}(V)$ given by a set of homogenous polynomials, i.e. X is a quasi-projective algebraic variety. In the case of an algebraically closed field, I can apply the theorem from Shafarevich's book to prove irreducibility (Theorem 1.26).

[image: Theorem from Shafarevich for algebraically closed field]

Take projective closure $\overline{X}$ of X and consider projection $\pi:\overline{X}\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}(V)$. I can prove condition on fibers in my particular case and since $\mathbb{P}(V)$ is irreducible as just a projective space then $\overline{X}$ is irreducible, hence $X$ as an open subset of $\overline{X}$ is also irreducible.

Shafarevich considers algebraically closed field throughout the first chapter. And I found exercise 12.4.D in Ravi Vakil's FOAG which states the same for a k-variety. And he doesn't suppose k to be algebraically closed. I think that projective variety in classical definition meets all conditions to be k-variety.
So, does it mean that I can generalize my statement to any non-algebraically closed field?

[image: Exercise from Ravi Vakil's notes][image: definition of k-variety]